# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API stops working on IIS as soon as web.config is edited and saved

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-8.0

.NET 8 app stops working on IIS on Windows Server 2012R2 (**IIS 8.5** installed) as soon as the `web.config` file is edited and saved.

You have to manually stop and start **IIS** for it to work again.

App Pool Settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

and below are site advance settings:
[image]

However on my local **IIS** deployment where **IIS 10** is installed on Windows 10, the app works perfectly.

could this be an issue with iis version 8.5 not supporting the latest .NET 8 app?

Comment: can you share your app pool config and site config ?

Comment: check now i have edited the answer, the apps which are built on .NET 5.0 works fine on the iis 8.5, but the ones built on .net 8.0 seems to have this issue.

Comment: I had some issues with same server , same version of .net8 application. Although microsoft claims that .net8 supports the server 2012R2 it's bit sketchy. For me the configuration that works is 'Idle Time-out Action' : Supend  and Site advanced settings "Preload Enabled" : false.  Btw our site is configured to always running with idle timeout 0. Not sure do you intent to have sam config. Also can you share your full app pool and site settings. Any logs in event viewer ?

Comment: don't know about event viewer, how do we access that? edited the post again, i cannot trace the issue.

Comment: You can try and set your application to always running. and idle timeout to 0 and Idle timeout action to suspend. Restart your app pool and site and try to change web config again.

Comment: That Windows version reached end of life, so running any web app on it is at your own risks. People tend to use Windows releases that are fully supported, so that further discussions are meaningful for more audience.

Comment: The issue is unlikely to be directly related to a version of IIS (8.5) that does not support the latest .NET 8 applications. You can check in Event Viewer on Windows Server for any error messages or warnings related to your application or IIS.

Comment: Press the Win + R key combination, this will open the run window, type "eventvwr" and press enter, this will open the event viewer. Browse the event logs. In the selected event log, the right panel will display the corresponding events. Browse the event list for error or warning messages related to your application or IIS. Click an error or warning to view details.